# How to show my data inside the template code?

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, python-3.6

template is not render..

I'm trying to display my content to the template page by django.

how display the content from view to the template.

here is the template code:

```
  <html>
      <body>
          {% if latest_question_list %}
           <ul>
               {% for question in latest_question_list %}
               <li><a href="/projectapp/{{question.id}}/">{{ question.question_text }}</a></li>
               {% endfor %}
           </ul>
           {% elae %}
               <p>No polls are available.</p>
          {% endif %}
      </body>
   </html>
```

here view.py page code:

```
def index(request)
  latest_question_list = Question.object.order_by('-pub_date')[:5]
  template = loader.get_template('projectapp/index.html')
  context = {
        'latest_question_list':latest_question_list,
   }
  return HttpResponse(template.render(context, request))
```

Comment: What is the question/the problem?  Note: you misspelled `{% elae %}`.

Comment: What's the problem or error that is happening? Does the template get rendered? The context is not being showed in the template?

Comment: no, it not render